# Creating array of string from the array of dictionaries in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary, swift-dictionary

I have JSON response as given below:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "demo",            
            "last_name": "test"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,                
            "name": "test",                
            "last_name": null
        },
        {
            "id": 15,
            "name": "test",                
            "last_name": null
        }
    ],
    "message": "List fetched successfully"
}
```

From the above response, I would like to create an array of strings which is a combination of values of the keys

> name

and

> last_name

from the above-given response. How can I achieve array of strings as given below:

`["<name last_name>","<name last_name>","<name last_name>"]`

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you researched and tried to decode the json, have you researched how to iterate over an array or how to use high-order functions in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create your structs to decode the JSON (note that I'm only appending last_name if it's not nil):

```
struct Model: Codable {
   let status: Bool
   let data: [DataEntry]
   let message: String
}

struct DataEntry: Codable {
   let id: Int
   let name: String
   let last_name: String?
}
```

Once you decode your JSON, you can obtain the array you want by using the map function:

```
stringArray = decodedData.data.map { 
   var string = $0.name
   if $0.last_name != nil { 
      string.append(" ")
      string.append($0.last_name!)
   }
   return string
}
```